# Is increasing gyro , accelerometer sensor range is good or bad ? how does it affect the accuracy

Tags: sensors, imu, accelerometer, gyroscope

I've been using mpu6050 IMU unit ( gyro + accelerometer  )

I found that I can set acc range to +/- 2g or 4g till 16 g

and same for gyro +/- 250 deg/sec , 500 deg/sec and so

I know that they are low cost and full noise , so which settings to the range are best to ensure higher accuracy ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor#Resolution 
But won't this increase the error ?

Comment: It will effect the resolution of your application.

Now the most important question is: What is the application? Which acceleration/velocities can be expected? 

The highest accuracy will be achieved with the lowest possible range.

Comment: If your application has a lot of vibrations noise (i.e.: quadcopter) having great accuracy does not matter. If your application may detect shocks you want the highest possible range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smaller the range, the more sensitive the device will be. So, in that sense, a smaller range is better. However, the downside of a smaller range is that movement of the robot will be more likely to exceed the range of the sensor.

You should select the smallest range which you're sure will never be exceeded by normal operation of your robot.

Or, the smallest range within which you want the robot to be under control. I.E. the range might be exceeded during a crash, but at that point control is pretty irrelevant.